# Upgrading to Express 4 and my sessions and passport no longer work

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I was reading in upgrading to express 4 that the order of app.use has to come after my app.get and app.post routes.

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'public'));
app.set('view engine', 'hjs');

// Initialize Passport!  Also use passport.session() middleware, to support
// persistent login sessions (recommended).
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname,'public','images','favicon.ico')));
app.use(cookieParser());
//app.use(express.json());
//app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));

//authentication
app.get('/app', ensureAuthenticated,appRoutes.app);
app.get('/app/:name', ensureAuthenticated,appRoutes.main);
app.get('/views/app/:name', ensureAuthenticated, appRoutes.index);
app.get('/views/app/:name/*', ensureAuthenticated, appRoutes.partials);


app.get('/',routes.home);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

I upgraded and now my passport authentication is not working.  I moved it above the routes and below and either way I get no error just does not authenticate and set a session.

Answer (score 0):

> I was reading in upgrading to express 4 that the order of app.use has to come after my app.get and app.post routes.

Nonsense ! Where did you read that ?

The only thing that comes close to what you're saying is this line from Expres 3.x to 4.x Migrating Guide :

> app.router has been removed. Middleware and routes are now executed in the order they're added. Your code should move any calls to app.use that came after app.use(app.router) after any routes (HTTP verbs).

But it does **not** mean that *every* `app.use` call should go *after* the routes (HTTP Verbs). Only the ones that you *used* to put *after* `app.use(app.router)` in your *old Express 3.x code*. Is that more clear ?

Regarding your issue, from Passport's docs :

> Note that enabling session support is entirely optional, though it is
>   recommended for most applications. If enabled, be sure to use
>   express.session() before passport.session() to ensure that the login
>   session is restored in the correct order.

So you should change :

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname,'public','images','favicon.ico')));
app.use(cookieParser());
//app.use(express.json());
//app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));
```

to :

```
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname,'public','images','favicon.ico')));
app.use(cookieParser());
//app.use(express.json());
//app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Hope that helps.